# Leaflet JS - external controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Is it possible to have external controls for zooming the image? I have looked into documentation, but I couldn't find a possible solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image-map"></div>

<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="-">-</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var map = L.map('image-map', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 4,
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

var w = 2000,
    h = 1500,
    url = 'http://kempe.net/images/newspaper-big.jpg';

var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(map);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/u51pgv4h/2/

Comment: what about `map.setZoom` ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth Hey, good find! I was able to solve with something like       $('#plus').click(function () {
       map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1)
      })
      $('#minus').click(function () {
       map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)
      })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to SupunPraneeth, I solved it with the following:

```
 $('#plus').click(function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1)
  })
  $('#minus').click(function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)
  })
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/j7w9qure/